# How do I expand Project Explorer to the bottom of my eclipse screen?

Tags: eclipse, view, perspective

I recently had to delete all my projects in eclipse and re-import them, and it messed up the view organization I had (I had never realized I could save a view until now). I want to use the Team Synchronizing Perspective in Eclipse, but I want the Project Explorer section to go to the bottom of the screen.

for example, in the Java perspective,
[image]

The package explorer goes to the bottom of the screen. but on the Team Sync Perspective, that I want to stay on, I can't get the Project explorer view to go to the bottom of the screen (and I know one is the package and one is the project explorer, I tried adding package explorer to the sync perspective and it also doesn't show up how I want).

Team Sync Perspective:
[image]

Does anyone know how to do what I'm asking? I've googled plenty and can't find the answer. I'm assuming it's simple and I just can't find the steps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this animated gif to rearrange views in a perspective. Left click on view's title bar and drag and drop the view wherever you need it.

[image]
Refer this [help guide](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-3h.htm)

Comment: you're amazing, thank you! I knew you could re-arrange them, but didn't realize it was kind of like a puzzle of re-arranging the bottom section off to the side so that the project explorer on the left could expand down.